# How to use metaprogramming in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, metaprogramming

I have a bunch of UILabels which I named by the week days (`SundayLabel`, `MondayLabel`, etc)

I have information per day in a dictionary of the day number as a key and some text as the value

```
0 => "info for sunday"
1 => "info for monday"
...
6 => "info for saturday"
```

Since all labels are structured the same, how can I make one method that would put the info for a day to the correct label

```
-(void)setTextForDay:(NSinteger)dayNum{

?

}
```

In ruby I know I can do something like

```
self.send("#{Date::DAYNAMES[0]}Label=", "info for sunday")
```

Comment: In most languages you would use an array...

Comment: Make an `NSDictionary` where the days are keys, or an `NSArray` where you will have `ENUM` for accessing the String you need

Store the strings for days

Comment: You've noticed `IBOutletCollection`?

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, there are ways to do this in Obj-C because Obj-C has a very good reflection. For instance, if you realize that every property has a getter (and I am assuming you are actually using `@property` for your labels), you can do:

```
NSString *getterName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Label", dayName];
SEL getterSelector = NSSelectorFromString(getterName);
UILabel *dayLabel = [self performSelector:getterSelector];
```

(you will probably get some ARC warnings).

However, what you have cannot be considered as good code. It's unnecessarily complicated. Usually, you would use an array

```
NSArray *dayLabels = @[self.mondayLabel, ..., self.sundayLabel];
UILabel *dayLabel = dayLabels[dayNum];
```

There is actually no need to keep the labels as separate variables. You can define an enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Day) {
    Monday = 0,
    ...
    Sunday
};
```

and index using `self.dayLabels[Monday]`. It's equally readable and simpler to use.